# How can I assign new values to a selection in a pipe operator?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn the dplyr package and I don't understand how to assign new values to a selection of a dataframe while in a pipe operation.

edit: I am trying to replace all cells that contain 10 with NA.

Example:

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
  new_df$column1[grepl("10", new_df$column1)] <- NA
```

Which return the following error:

```
Error in old_df %>% new_df$column1[grepl("10", new_df$column1)] <- NA : could not find function "%>%<-"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible `dplyr` solutions, depending on what exactly the question is asking for.

First, some test data.

```
old_df <- data.frame(column1 = as.character(c(5:15, 90:110)),
                     column2 = c(10:20, 90:110))
```

**1.** Replace all elements in `column1` where the *pattern* "10" can be found by `NA`.

```
old_df %>%
  mutate(column1 = ifelse(grepl("10", column1), NA, column1))
```

**2.** Replace all the elements in `column1` where the *value* "10" can be found by `NA`.

```
old_df %>%
  mutate(column1 = ifelse(column1 == "10", NA, column1))
```

If the pattern or value is numeric, remove the quotes.

### Base R

Anyway, base R is more suited for this problem. To replace values by `NA`, use base function `is.na<-`.

```
new_df <- old_df
is.na(new_df$column1) <- grepl("10", new_df$column1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, solution 1 was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`a %>% b(c)`, unrelated to dplyr, is simply a shortcut for `b(a, c)`. In your code, this would imply writing

```
new_df <- `[<-`(old_df, new_df$column1, grepl("10", new_df$column1), NA)
```

(because `x[i] <- v` in R is the same as `` x <- `[<-`(x, i, value = v) ``, where `[<-` is the name of a function that performs the subset replacement.)

And that is clearly nonsensical.

(The error message is slightly misleading since what actually happens behind the scene is even more complex. We don’t need to dissect this in detail, since that’s clearly not what you had in mind.)

The point is that you can only use pipes to substitute the call syntax explained initially, and for nothing else (don’t attempt to put it everywhere). Don’t try to force a square peg through a round hole. If you want to replace some values, either do this directly:

```
new_df <- old_df
new_df$column1[grepl("10", new_df$column1)] <- NA
```

Or use dplyr:

```
new_df <- mutate(old_df, column1 = ifelse(grepl("10", column1), NA, column1))
```

… and if you want you can *now* replace the conventional function call syntax with a pipe, though it doesn’t really fulfil a purpose here:

```
new_df <- old_df %>% mutate(column1 = ifelse(grepl("10", column1), NA, column1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. The reason I wanted to do it in a pipe was so that I wouldn't have to reassign it repeatedly to the same variable. This has been really clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to replace value 10 with NA. Is that correct? If so,

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
  filter( column1 == "10" ) %>%
  mutate ( column1 = NA)
```

will provide the subset of data which had 10 with NA now.
But since you need to keep the rest of data,

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
  mutate ( column1 = ifelse((column1 == "10"), NA, column1))
```

will help.

Comment: Now you’ve deleted all values ≠ `"10"`, which is probably not what OP had in mind.

Comment: Thank for the help I want to indeed replace the values with 10. When I insert a starts_with() or grepl() function it empties the whole dataframe

Comment: True, it is unclear what he needs. May need to provide a different solution if this is not what he wants.